# #define vs self.method for checking allocation

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, cocoa-touch, c-preprocessor

I wondered what is the right way to go to check for allocation (or other things) for objects. I did some performance tests myself and found that checking without the method call saves "huge" amounts of time. Which way is regarded as good coding? Test and result below.

the define:

```
#define checkUM if (!um) {um =  [[UtilityMaster alloc]init]; }
```

vs the method:

```
-(void) checkUtility {
    if (!um) {um =  [[UtilityMaster alloc]init]; }
}
```

code for checking:

```
int imax = 1000000000;
int i = 0;
IFD100(@"check method")
while (i <= imax) {
    [self checkUtility];
    i++;
}
IFD100(@"check method end")
i = 0;
IFD100(@"check define")
while (i <= imax) {
    checkUM;
    i++;
}
IFD100(@"check define end")
```

check 1:

```
2013-06-25 18:36:16.712  check method
2013-06-25 18:36:27.669  check method end  <-- 10.957 secs
2013-06-25 18:36:27.670  check define
2013-06-25 18:36:30.128  check define end  <-- 2.458 secs
```

check 2:

```
2013-06-25 18:37:18.900  check method
2013-06-25 18:37:28.678  check method end  <-- 9.778 secs
2013-06-25 18:37:28.679  check define
2013-06-25 18:37:31.136  check define end  <-- 2.457 secs
```

Comment: The time difference is the 1 billion method calls that the macro doesn't make.

Comment: BTW - your log statements are reversed. You log "check define" but then test the method call.

Comment: Yeah i liked that reversal too haha

Comment: This is a micro benchmark and optimizing micro benchmarks is rarely a good use of time.

Comment: shit shit shit, interpreted it the right way though, going to edit

Comment: Using the define will save **2.5 hours** if you run the test for a trillion iterations instead of just a billion! Sheesh, Objective-C methods are so slow!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Preprocessor macros are ugly, especially if you are trying to emulate functions using them. So don't do that. At the same time, I doubt that this be the bottleneck in your algorithm. If it is, then better make an inline function and let the compiler do its job optimizing it.

Comment: Inline functions do look interesting, i'll have a read on them. As for the macros, i found them very helpful negating repetitive code (like debugging with NSLog).

Answer (score 5):

If you are making the call enough, it may be worth taking considerations for the performance, but keep in mind, you are calling it a **billion** times. This is means that it takes about 9 nanoseconds extra per call. That is not a huge amount of time. Also, keep in mind that #define is a macro meaning that it essentially copy pastes the code to everywhere you call it. Interpret as you will, it is your choice, but I recommend going with methods because they are simpler and easier to expand etc. If there is anything that demands the extra 9 nanoseconds per call, it should probably be written in straight c anyway.

Answer (score 3):

That's a saving of 9 seconds over a billion iterations.

How about the time saving you get from not seeing that macro and trying to figure out what it does. Also `checkUtility` isn't a very clear method name. You think it's makes sense now, when you come back to it in two months you'll wonder what you were doing, and then you'll have to look it up. The same with the macro. Either way, you've optimised your code and saved 9 seconds, but you'll waste more than that figuring out what you're doing.

[Write Code For Humans Not Machines](http://programmer.97things.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Write_Code_for_Humans_not_Machines)

Comment: checkUtility was only for testing purposes, it is removed already.

Comment: As for the naming and macros, "UtilityMaster" --> "um" is only for my personal use/needs. It was implemented in all my projects so far and relieves me of writing simple tasks over and over again. I understand that maybe someday someone else might have to work with my code and i made sure my own classes are comment heavy.

Comment: BTT: I find it very disturbing all of you compared my time writing the code to the actual computing time it takes a device. What if a billion people are actually using the app many times a day...it is grossly negligent in my oppinion to just set them even. Also do not forget this test was made on a simulator, the iPhone 4s took over 1.5 minutes vs 0.5 minutes for these Billion iterations. And a big chunk of that is the iteration itself i guess. Sry for the triple post, too late for edit in the first and to few allowed chars for the second.

Comment: I think you misunderstood our objections. Yes, saving time is important. But really, run your code through a profiler and see where the real hot spots are. I bet you a few extra message sends are the least of your problems. And your ability to service and update your program that billions of people are using is directly related to the maintainability of your code.